# AVPlayer/AudioPlayer: No error but no sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avplayer, avaudiosession

I've tried a dozen different ways to try and stream [this radio station](http://tunein.com/radio/KOIL-1290-s33415/). However, no matter how many different ways I tried none of them have worked. I realize that the link provided is not a .mp3 file, or really any sort of audio file (I'm not sure where to find an audio file of a streamed radio station), but I've tried other URLs that are with the same lack of good results. When I try this in my viewdidload method, there is no error but no result:

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

// Init player
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tunein.com/radio/KOIL-1290-s33415/?streamid=61377300"]];
AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: playerItem];
[audioPlayer play];
```

I've also tried all of these ways (each way is in it's own /* ... */):

```
/*
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tunein.com/radio/KOIL-1290-s33415/"]];
NSError *error;

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
else
    [audioPlayer play];
 */


/*
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

              // You may find a test stream at <http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8>.

              AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

              //(optional) [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];

              AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

              player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];

              //(optional) [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];

 */

/*
NSString* resourcePath = @"http://streema.com/radios/play/7146"; //your url
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:resourcePath];

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

audioPlayer.delegate = self;

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
 */
/*
//download file and play from disk
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", docDirPath , @"listen"];
[audioData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSError *error;
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
if (player == nil) {
    NSLog(@"AudioPlayer did not load properly: %@", [error description]);
} else {
    [player play];
}
 */
```

Edit: I've also tried [this](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer), but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, in every single one of your attempts, is that your AVPlayer is referred to only by a local variable:

```
AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: playerItem];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Thus, you tell the player to player and then your code comes to an end and the player is destroyed before it has a chance to start playing anything! If you want it to play, you need to make the player *persist* at least for the duration that it is to be playing. Make it an instance variable / property of a view controller or other class instance that will last that long.

Comment: Wow. Ok I'm trying that now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it was just that. For example, I just tried this:

    `NSString* resourcePath = @"http://broadcast.infomaniak.net/radionova-high.mp3"; 

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:resourcePath];

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.audioPlayer play];`

with the property set as: @property AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer, and the AVAudipPlayerDelegate, and I'm still having no results.

Comment: I do not say it was _just_ that. I know nothing about the particular URL you are trying to use. But what I said is right. You were _never_ going to hear anything because your player was vanishing instantly in a puff of smoke before it could play. Let's solve one problem at a time. Convince yourself that now you can play _something_ (which was impossible before; with your code, you could not play anything at all). Then if you have another question about your URL, using code that actually works to play something, ask about that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Thanks a ton for pointing that out. The problem is I've tried so many different URLs and can't get any of them to work.

Comment: Don't use a streaming URL to test. Start with a file URL for a sound file in your app bundle. Start small, grow big.